# ORA-01427: single-row Subquery Returns More Than One Row for Update

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sql-update

Hi I am trying to execute but getting error single row subquery returns more than one row.

```
 update  upld_mktprice
                        set (upld_mktprice.orig_security, upld_mktprice.stk_exch, upld_mktprice.stk_group, upld_mktprice.instr_type) =
                                                                (select  security.security,nvl(upld_mktprice.stk_exch, 
                                                                nvl(security.stk_exch,'DIRECT')), 
                                                                security.stk_group,
                                                                decode(upld_mktprice.source,'FOREX','X','S') as instr_type -- HLAMUAT-1457146: Passing DIRECT as a default value for HLAM. confirmed by Dheeren/Prasanth.
                                                                from    v_security_all security
                                                                where   upld_mktprice.security =  Decode(security.asset_type,'OPT',security.stk_sec_id||' '||substr(security.security,instrb(security.security, ' ', 1,1)+3, length(security.security)),security.stk_sec_id)
                                                                and     rectype = 'L'),
                        upld_mktprice.currency = nvl(upld_mktprice.currency,''),
                        upld_mktprice.value_date = nvl(upld_mktprice.value_date,''),
                        upld_mktprice.amc_code = 'AMC'
          Where   exists  (select 1
                            from    v_security_all security
                            where   upld_mktprice.security =  Decode(security.asset_type,'OPT',security.stk_sec_id||' '||substr(security.security,instrb(security.security, ' ', 1,1)+3, length(security.security)),security.stk_sec_id)
                            and rectype = 'L')
            and     upld_mktprice.orig_security is null
            and       upld_mktprice.user_id       = 'SRINIVAS'
            and       upld_mktprice.source       = 'MKTPRICEMAN';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error pretty much speaks for itself. The portion of your query below is returning more than one row. There is no way for us to validate because we do not have the data that you have. It might also be a bit easier to troubleshoot if you used table aliases in your update statement.

```
(SELECT security.security,
                   NVL (upld_mktprice.stk_exch, NVL (security.stk_exch, 'DIRECT')),
                   security.stk_group,
                   DECODE (upld_mktprice.source, 'FOREX', 'X', 'S')     AS instr_type -- HLAMUAT-1457146: Passing DIRECT as a default value for HLAM. confirmed by Dheeren/Prasanth.
              FROM v_security_all security
             WHERE     upld_mktprice.security =
                       DECODE (security.asset_type,
                               'OPT',    security.stk_sec_id
                                      || ' '
                                      || SUBSTR (security.security,
                                                   INSTRB (security.security,
                                                           ' ',
                                                           1,
                                                           1)
                                                 + 3,
                                                 LENGTH (security.security)),
                               security.stk_sec_id)
                   AND rectype = 'L')
```

Comment: I trying to execute with 'distinct' in select statement but also same error raising.

Comment: Is it possible that more than one record is returned based on this where clause?

Comment: Yes,by using nvl. Decode (Nvl(security.cll_dp_stk,'N') ,'L',security.security, Decode(security.asset_type,'OPT',security.stk_sec_id||' '||substr(security.security,instrb(security.security, ' ', 1,1)+3, length(security.security)),security.stk_sec_id)  )